# eclipse neon - ignore json error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

I got few JSON in my project and after importing them to Eclipse *Neon* I saw red mark on file (and on project) complaining "JSON Problem".

My question is how can I disable/skip/ignore the JSON errors from Eclipse Neon,

Comment: Can you show the specific errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure JSON validation and error marking under **Preferences** > **JSON** > **JSON Files** > **Validation**.

[image]

It can be configured for the entire workspace or on a per-project level (see the link on the preferences page "Configure Project Specific Settings..."

Comment: Sadly, Validation is not the only source for JSON errors, some are emitted by "language servers" and some from somewhere else.